# How to quell qmake's "WARNING: Failure to find:"?

Tags: qmake

I'm using `PRE_TARGETDEPS` to generate source files, and I'm adding the generated source files to `SOURCES` for compilation.

The output of my generator obviously doesn't exist at the time qmake is run, so qmake outputs `WARNING: Failure to find:` for each of the to-be-created source files.

How can I quell this warning, since I know my `PRE_TARGETDEPS` is going to produce those files?

Or, is there a better way to generate intermediate files using qmake?

### Example

Here's a complete `test.pro` file that exhibits the problem:

```
TEMPLATE = lib

preprocess.commands += cat test.cc.in | sed 's/a/0/g' > test.0.cc ;
preprocess.commands += cat test.cc.in | sed 's/a/1/g' > test.1.cc ;
preprocess.depends = test.cc.in
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += preprocess
PRE_TARGETDEPS += preprocess

SOURCES = test.0.cc test.1.cc
```

Place this in an empty folder, and also create an empty `test.cc.in` file.  Run `qmake`, and you'll see these warnings:

```
WARNING: Failure to find: test.0.cc
WARNING: Failure to find: test.1.cc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How can I quell this warning**

From my reading of the qmake code, it looks like you can:

- *either* have qmake ignore any filenames that don't exist - in which case they won't get built by your later steps
- *or* have it write these warnings

I don't think either of these would be satisfactory for you.

---

Here's my reasoning.... I had a hunt for the text `Failure to find` in a Qt distribution I had to hand: qt4.8.1.

It appeared 3 times in in `qmake/generators/makefile.cpp`. The two blocks of code look like this:

```
QStringList
MakefileGenerator::findFilesInVPATH(QStringList l, uchar flags, const QString &vpath_var)
{
....
                    debug_msg(1, "%s:%d Failure to find %s in vpath (%s)",
                              __FILE__, __LINE__,
                              val.toLatin1().constData(), vpath.join("::").toLatin1().constData());
                    if(flags & VPATH_RemoveMissingFiles)
                        remove_file = true;
                    else if(flags & VPATH_WarnMissingFiles)
                        warn_msg(WarnLogic, "Failure to find: %s", val.toLatin1().constData());
....
                else if(flags & VPATH_WarnMissingFiles)
                    warn_msg(WarnLogic, "Failure to find: %s", val.toLatin1().constData());
```

and this is called with:

```
        l = findFilesInVPATH(l, (comp.flags & Compiler::CompilerRemoveNoExist) ?
                             VPATH_RemoveMissingFiles : VPATH_WarnMissingFiles, "VPATH_" + comp.variable_in);
```

So the flags parameter passed in to the first block will be either `RemoveMissingFiles`  or `WarnMissingFiles`, depending on `comp.flags & Compiler::CompilerRemoveNoExist`.

---

**Or, is there a better way to generate intermediate files using qmake?**

I'm not sure that it's better  - i.e. it's certainly complex - but this is what is done where I work...

In the .pro file, a system call is done, that:

1. generates the required files,
2. and then writes out their names to stdout.

Here's an example from the .pro, to show how it would be called:

```
SOURCES    += $$system( python my_script_name.py )
```

You can of course pass arguments in to the python script, if you like

Things to note/limitations:

- This means that the python script gets run whenever you run `qmake`, but not during individual `make` invocations
- Each invocation of python really slows down our qmake steps - taking roughly twice as long as running qmake without launching python - but you could always use a different scripting language

This would fix your problem, in that by the time qmake processes the `SOURCES` value, the files have been created by the script.

Comment: Brilliant.  The populate-`SOURCES`-using-`$$system()` technique works perfectly.  I'm just using a simple shell script, so it doesn't noticeably add to the qmake execution time.  Thank you.

Comment: And if I use `QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS` as the processor for the source list generated by `$$system()`, I can set `.depends`, and it correctly re-runs the script when `make` is run.