# qmake pre-build step before ANY compilation

Tags: qt, qmake

There are several questions on SO regarding how to create a pre-build step for `qmake`, I can do that with this in my `.pro` file:

```
versionTarget.target = ../VersionData/versioning.h
versionTarget.depends = FORCE
win32: versionTarget.commands = cd $$PWD; python.exe ./version_getter.py -p $$TARGET
else:  versionTarget.commands = cd $$PWD; python ./version_getter.py -p $$TARGET

PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../VersionData/versioning.h
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += versionTarget
```

Now, the problem is that this approach is not a build step per se but just another build target, so if I have the `-j` flag configured for `make` it runs my script in *parallel* with the other build jobs.  This is very bad, because my script creates/updates a header file - having it change part way through the compilation is not acceptable.

So, is there anyway I can have this script executed before *any* compilation is ran?  I know I can create another script and call the `version_getter.py` and `qmake` in sequence from that, but this is not desirable as I would have to compile from the command line rather than from within Qt Creator.

---

### Update

The complete `.pri` file that is included by every one of my sub-projects is below:

```
CONFIG += thread
QT += core \
      gui

versionTarget.target = ../VersionData/versioning.h
versionTarget.depends = FORCE
win32: versionTarget.commands = cd $$PWD; python.exe ./version_getter.py -p $$TARGET
else:  versionTarget.commands = cd $$PWD; python ./version_getter.py -p $$TARGET

PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../VersionData/versioning.h
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += versionTarget

DEPENDPATH += ../VersionData
INCLUDEPATH += ../VersionData
HEADERS += ../VersionData/versioning.h

UI_HEADERS_DIR = $${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/include/Qui
DESTDIR = $(SYREN_PATH)

!win32-msvc {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
}
```

But this still results in the same parallel behaviour.  I thought it may have been due to my use of `ccache`, but turning it off made no difference (other than being much slower of course).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another option would be to start with the project file snippet in your original question, and also ensure that qmake is aware that `versioning.h` is a dependency for the other build targets in your project file —

- Add the full path to `versioning.h` to your `HEADERS` variable.
- Add the folder in which `versioning.h` resides to your `DEPENDPATH` variable.

(Caveat: if you run qmake when `versioning.h` doesn't exist, it will emit "WARNING: Failure to find: versioning.h" — [the only workaround for that warning is to use the `system()` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14111649/64860), as I described in my other answer.)

### Example

Create `test.pro` containing the following:

```
versionTarget.target = ../versioning.h
versionTarget.depends = FORCE
versionTarget.commands = sleep 5s ; touch ../versioning.h
PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../versioning.h
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += versionTarget

SOURCES = test.c
HEADERS = ../versioning.h
DEPENDPATH = ..
```

Create `test.c` containing the following:

```
#include "../versioning.h"
```

Run `qmake`.  It will output `WARNING: Failure to find: ../versioning.h`.

Run `make -j9`.  It will run `versionTarget.commands` (which sleeps for 5 seconds to exaggerate any multiprocessing problems), and, after that is done, run the command to compile `test.c`.

(And if you examine the generated `Makefile`, you'll see that `test.o` depends on both `test.c` and `../versioning.h`, so Make should correctly figure out that it can't run the command to compile `test.c` before the command to create/update `../versioning.h`.)

Comment: Would you mind posting an example?  I added `DEPENDPATH += ../VersionData HEADERS += ../VersionData/versioning.h` after the code I posted in the question and the behaviour is no different.

Comment: It works perfectly the first time, but building immediately afterwards causes it to run in parallel again.  I tried adding a `system(touch ../versionData/versioning.h)` to 'trick' `make` into thinking it has changed, but it's not that stupid...  I think I may have to concede defeat with `qmake` and use your first answer!

Comment: I've updated my question with my complete `.pri`, can you spot anything stupid with it?  I `include "versioning.h"` in the source file of an 'About' dialog.

Comment: Only the about dialog object file has that dependency, would I need to add it to every source file!?

Comment: Well, you might not have a problem, then.  If you do what I described in this answer, and if all the source files that need to use the values defined in `versioning.h` actually include that header file, then `qmake` should automatically figure out dependencies and generate a Makefile reflecting those dependencies.  `make` may choose to build some targets that don't depend on `versioning.h` in parallel with `versioning.h`.

Comment: Of course! I was being an idiot, `make` has outsmarted me. Again.

Comment: I get the warning you mention and I realised that it is because qmake is generating the makefile wrongly. When the dependency is specified the path is in the form d:\Work\...\version.h and when the rule is specified it is in the form D:/Work/.../version.h. Obviously these don't match. If I manually edit the makefile the warning goes away.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`system()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command) qmake command — it runs when you run `qmake`, which happens before `make` runs any build commands.

```
win32: PYTHON=python.exe
else:  PYTHON=python
system(cd $$PWD; $$PYTHON ./version_getter.py -p ../VersionData/versioning.h)
```

Comment: There's a serious problem with this approach, because `qmake` is ran for clean builds and even if there are no changes.  This is why using scripts as targets is promoted.

Comment: system() worked for me.  Under Windows using Qt 5.9.2 I could not get my pre-build scripts to execute using PRE_TARGETDEPS. However, PRE_TARGETDEPS worked fine under macOS target builds.  The problem with calling pre-build script from system()  is that it will not run after doing a clean and I remove my auto-generated version.h. It only runs when qmake is run.

Comment: smokris: Your example doesn't work – you have to separate commands with `&&`, not a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you inspect the Makefile produced by qmake there is always the first Makefile rule named "first" that depends on another rule debug (or release) that contains the instructions for the build. Id est, something like this :

```
...
MAKEFILE      = Makefile
first: debug
...
```

In order to create a pre-build step, we should hack that rule to depend on another with higher priority.

Something like

```
...
MAKEFILE      = Makefile
first: prebuild debug
prebuild:
    do_your_instructions
...
```

This would actually be equal to something like this:

```
...
MAKEFILE      = Makefile
first: debug
...
first: prebuild 
prebuild:
    do_your_instructions
...
```

which could be easily hacked in a qmake project by doing:

```
# $$PWD/test_prebuild is a batch with the instructions to execute before every build
!build_pass:prebuild.commands = $$PWD/test_prebuild
!build_pass:first.depends = prebuild
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += prebuild first
```

Please note that "!build_pass:" ensures that you write this prebuild rule only in Makefile (and not in Makefile.Debug or Makefile.Release) preventing the execution of test_prebuild multiple times. 
Please note that this is hack is possible because "first" is not reserved (though is names a [qmake primitive](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#first-variablename).

In my case it worked fine: I hope this trick could help others as well.

Comment: I also noticed that, due to the way qmake builds the makefile, if the rule is named FORCE instead of first the commands are run  not only before any build phase, but also after any regeneration of the makefile

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution to this!  You can leverage `QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS` to force a synchronous prebuild operation, and this works when using *parallel* compilation (make -j flag)! I can't take credit for this solution, I found it at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50619989/3220983