# QMake - how to add a post-build step after EVERY build

Tags: c++, bash, qmake, build-script

Having a bit of trouble - I've added the following lines to qmake in order to get it to copy files into the app bundle on Mac.

```
mac {
    QMAKE_POST_LINK = $$PWD/package_mac.sh
}
```

The .sh file runs sometimes, and seems to work (at the moment it just runs `touch geese` which creates a file named `geese` in the build directory (excellent!).

But, it doesn't run every time I build, it seems to be only when files are changed. Really, I want a way to get qmake to copy over all my game's resources into the correct places on each platform (so build folder on Windows, app package on Mac, etc...) **every** time I build.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `POST_TARGETDEPS` (with `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS`)? The downside to this approach is that you'll have to create some sort of dummy file (since to the best of my knowledge `.PHONY` isn't supported by `qmake`), which you should probably also `clean` later.

Taking your example:

```
mac {
    package-script = $$PWD/package_mac.sh
}

package-target.target = $$PWD/package.tmp
package-target.depends = FORCE
package-target.commands = $$package-script
```

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864689/qmake-pre-build-step-before-any-compilation) for a similar discussion.)

Comment: 'target.CONFIG=phony' got same effect as FORCE. It's overlooked in documentation but is in code since early Qt4