# Run qmake on a project file at each build even if it is unchanged

Tags: c++, git, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I would like qt creator runs qmake on a project file every time I build the whole project, even if such file is unchanged.
I need this because within such .pro file I run a little script to get the latest git hash of my sources. The git hash it is appended to the version string of the program (a define) and coded within the executable.

Thanks to all

Comment: This is what you need instead. Just make .pro file to behave and no need to rebuild the project with qmake all the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864689/qmake-pre-build-step-before-any-compilation

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly what I was looking for!