# How to tell qmake to build selected file always without clean to all?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Some file I have need to be built every time when make is called. But I don't need to clean all compiled ones.

May be make clean partially or remove obj of selected file to some resolve this topic.

---

The actual issue:

In that file I have generated timedatestamp to show it from About Dialog. File is not being changed after created and date isn't actually.

Comment: Are those files being updated every time? If the files are changing then isn't it already compiling those? Can you please add a little bit context to this? The relevant parts of `.pro` file would be helpful.

Comment: In that file I have generated timedatestamp to show it from About Dialog. File is not being changed after created and date isn't actually.

Comment: Sounds like something you want to retain, right? Why don't you write a registry entry (I'm assuming Windows) or a temporary file in `/etc/your-app/about` (i.e. Linux) and use that? Generate only if it doesn't exist or some other logic according to your setup.

Comment: FYI: [SO: qmake pre-build step before ANY compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881164/7478597). Instead of a `touch` (like in the accepted answer) this could be as well a redirected output of `date`. (Btw. we used something very similar but we use CMake.)