# Delete directory before compilation

Tags: qt, qmake

I am trying to delete a directory containing sub-directories and files before the compilation starts from a qmake pro file:

```
if exists($$OUT_PWD/android-build/src) del_tree($$OUT_PWD/android-build/src)
```

I tried different commands like `QMAKE_DEL_TREE` and `$(DEL_TREE)` but nothing worked. How can I delete an eventually existing directory?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864689/qmake-pre-build-step-before-any-compilation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that `$(DEL_TREE)` works fine. It did not work due to a mkspec bug in the Android Windows build invironment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-25373